# Allow customer to only see logging information

Tags: azure, logging

We run a software application on azure for one of our customers. The customer want to see the performance of the systems. This consist of two parts. One is the metric information of the servers and they also want to see some information I want to provide by custom logging.

My plan is to give the customer access to the portal and only allow him access to the metric information and the custom tables.

It seems to me that by assigning a role to the customer I should be able to block all the other possibilities.
Does someone can me tell which actions I have to allow/forbid to achieve this? Or were I can find the information for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

Instead of giving Read access to the virtual machine which may breaks security policy, I'd recommend to go with Azure Log Analytics (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-overview
) workspace. That said, you will need to create a workspace which collects and stores server metrics (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-quick-collect-windows-computer) and other custom metrics.

Your customer will be given access to the workspace only which he can see all metrics in a dashboard. If there is a need for log filtering, you can use Log Analytics query language (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-log-search-transition)

Log Analytics is a paid service. You are given free up to 10 workspaces per subscription. The workspace is considered an Azure resource so the limit follows by subscription limit, which means you can create up to 800 workspaces per a resource group. A subscription can allow 800 * 800 (for reference if you would like to do capacity planning for your workspace-based solution). For Log Analytics pricing, read here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/log-analytics/).

Log Analytics is a good choice as its value proportion is to offer your customer intuitive dashboard to monitor their virtual machine performance, and to offer Near Real Time monitoring. And this solution is a cloud native compatibility.

There is a management solution which offers a bundle of VM capacity and performance monitoring which you can try now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-capacity

**Solution #2**

Log Analytics might not be your choice because it might add more Azure service and operational cost. If you need a cheaper cost, you would need to collect your virtual machine by Performance Counter which is a built-in feature in Windows OS. With Performance Counter you can export to Excel file, or visualize into Power BI or some custom chart.

**Other Solutions**

You can utilize Azure Monitor and API to get data, For example, this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricdefinitions/list. You would certainly need to visualize or format in some intuitive way to satisfy your customer. It can be a custom front-end web, or Power BI or even Excel with chart.

You can just query to Azure Blob Storage and use Stream Analytics combining with Power BI to visualize your data (https://thuansoldier.net/?p=7187).

There is not a single solution. This really depends on your existing resource capacity, financial stuff or so on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The customer is a big company which not allow users to install software (Power BI).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
 The customer is a big company which not allow users to install software (Power BI).
 The log analytics was something I have looked at, but has the problem that it is very hard for the user to select time-spans.  Couldn't find any simple settings as they are in the metric information in the portal.
. Or is there a way to make this easy for the customer?
I was planning to add the user to the portal as reader with only access to the metrics. This should be save as they are not able to change anything and shouldn't be able to reach the VM's